# Web Scraping - No outputs

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests

I have a list of product numbers that I want to use to look up their prices on this site: 'https://www.partsfinder.com/Catalog/Service/GetPartOptions'

Below code works to lookup the price of an individual product, I indeed get the price:

```
import requests

data = {"partOptionFilter":{"PartNumber":"0119000230","AlternativeOemId":"17155"}}
r = requests.post('https://www.partsfinder.com/Catalog/Service/GetPartOptions',json=data).json()
print(r['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])
```

However if I'm to do a loop, I get empty outputs:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\212677036\Documents\Copy of MIC Parts Review - July 26 19.xlsx')
PN = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Product code'])

#print(PN)
i = 0


Total_rows = PN.shape[0]
while i < Total_rows:
         #print(PN.iloc[i,0])
         data = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN.iloc[i,0], "AlternativeOemId": "17155"}}
         r = requests.post('https://www.partsfinder.com/Catalog/Service/GetPartOptions', json=data).json()
         print(r['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])
         i=i+1
```

I think the problem is the "AlternativeOemId" parameter, My list only has the "PartNumber" parameter.  If I simply get rid of the "alternativeOemId" I get an error.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What happens, if you skip the `AlternativeOemId` completely? Btw. are you sure you may call the web page with a high frequency? Please consider adding a sleep interval in your loop. Your web scraping actions could produce cosiderable traffic for the web server.

Comment: I get the error below:Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\212677036\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Maybe you can ask the company, who provides the web page, if there is something like a "wildcard value".